Mongoose Virtual Field Population Problem
I have a problem with current state of my database since it started with a very old backend wrapper. (Parse Server)
So here is the problem let's say I have two different collections Users and Stores each user has just one address.
const user = {
    id: "a1b2c3",
    _p_store: "Stores$x1y2z3"
}

const store = {
    id: "x1y2z3",
    _p_user: "Users$a1b2c3"
}

Id's of documents are not ObjectId, plain string.
Local keys are built in this fashion collection_name_of_foreign_collection + $ + foreign_id
Problem is I just cant use 'ref' in the schema to .populate() related field. So in order to populate it I need to transform it like value.split("$")[1] but since it would be the virtual field, I can't populate it either.
i tried this :
userSchema.virtual('store', {
  ref: 'Store',
  localField: '_p_store',
  foreignField: '_id',
  justOne: true,
  async get(this: any) {
    try {
      const storeId = this._p_store.split('$')[1];
      if (!storeId) return null;

      const store = await Store.findOne({ _id: storeId }).exec();
      return store;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching store:', error);
      return null;
    }
  },
});

const user = await User.findOne({ _id: 'a1b2c3' }).populate('store');

console.log(user);



an it logs :
{
    _id: "a1b2c3",
    store: Promise { <pending> },
}

how can I fix this problem, any idea is welcome.
I tried virtuals, no luck. Expecting to be able to natively do populate.

Are you in a position to do a batch update to change the actual values like this which would allow you to have localField: 'id', foreignField: '_p_user', in your virtual for store? An updateMany would be a good write operation.

Changing fields to different values is not an option. I need to be keep supporting the existing schemas.

Then the simplest way is just to use Model.aggregate instead of Model.populate as you can manipulate the values. Here is an example

You can use a Model.aggegate() to achieve this without using populate:

$match: find the document based on your criteria.
$set: a new field using a sub-string of the _p_store field value.
$lookup: the stores collection and use the new store field added to the user document previously as a reference to match against the id of the stores document.
$unwind: the store array to transform it into an object instead on an array.

const user = await User.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      id: "a1b2c3"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      store: {
        $substrBytes: [
          "$_p_store",
          7,
          -1
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "stores",
      localField: "store",
      foreignField: "id",
      as: "store"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$store"
  }
]);

See HERE for a working example.
Note: the user variable will be an array as opposed to the Model.findOne() method which returns a single document object.
